# PDO query not returning results in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have a function (below) which isn't returning a result set from a PDO query inside a foreach loop.  Not sure what could be the problem.  To explain a bit, I'm running PHP v5.6.3 and the $csv string passed to the function is something like:

```
$csv = "red, brown, blue";
```

After the str_getcsv is ran, print_r($colors) works as expected.  I've tried preparing the query and binding values inside or outside the loop with no success, and if I pull the query outside of the loop (and run it once) it works.

```
function generateColors($csv) {
    global $db; // Connect DB
    $colors = str_getcsv($csv, ","); //Converts the CSV to an array
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM colors WHERE slug = :slug");
    foreach ($colors as $slug) {
        $query->bindValue(':slug', $slug, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "COLOR: " .$slug;
        echo "<br>";
        var_dump($result);
    }
}
```

The output (below) shows that the loop is working, just the query seems to stop returning values after 1 iteration. Any help on why I'm getting a bool(false) instead of an array set like [column 1]=>value 1, [column 2]=>value 2, etc., would be greatly appreciated.

```
COLOR: red
array -> [column]=>value, [column]=value, etc. // returned as expected.
COLOR: brown
bool(false)
COLOR: blue
bool(false)
```

Comment: THE PROBLEM IS you are thinking that $slug of foreach will automaticlly equalizie $slug of bindvalue which is not going to happen. you need to put your bindValue code in foreach and then need to check

Comment: Edited function above to put bindValue back inside loop.  Unfortunately, still resulting in a bool(false).

Comment: Actually... putting it back inside the loop, I've noticed it returns the first result set properly (for the first loop run), however, all subsequent values in the loop are returning the bool(false).

Comment: that means you have record for first slug but not for others? I think i am clear?

Comment: Correct, my output is like this now:

    COLOR: red
    array(11) { ["slug"]=> string(15) "red" ["name"]=> string(15) "Red", etc...
    COLOR: brown
    bool(false)
    etc..

Comment: try to check out by directly going to db that this is correctly outputing or not? means  check other slugs related value are there in the db or not?

Comment: And if it is correct then please try to mark it as an your answer so that other can get help?

Comment: Correct.  If I write all queries out manually, they all return result sets.  It's almost as if the value of $result is being wiped out and not being repopulated as the loop continues?

Comment: Sop  i think you got your solution?

Comment: Apologies, but no.  The query is only returning a result on the first loop iteration, and no more. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the params inside the foreach. Before the foreach your variable `$slug` is not defined.

```
function generateColors($csv) {
    global $db; // Connect DB
    $colors = str_getcsv($csv, ","); //Converts the CSV to an array
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM colors WHERE slug = :slug");
    foreach ($colors as $slug) {
        $query->bindValue(':slug', $slug, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "COLOR: " .$slug;
        echo "<br>";
        var_dump($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do see your point.  In fact, I've been tinkering so long with this that I mistakenly should've put it back inside before posting ;)

However, even putting the bindValue back inside the loop, I'm still getting a bool(false). :-/